# find the folder along with the file names which has my string in it?

Tags: linux, search, text, grep, find

I need to find the folder names along with the file names which has my string in their contents. I am in this directory "`/data/queue/data`" and I have lot of folders in the same directory and inside those each folders, I have various files.

I want to run a command which can find me folder name and the file names which has a particular string like this "`badezimmer`" in their contents. What is the fastest way to do this?

Below are the folders in this directory "`/data/queue/data`" and each of those folders has various files in it.

```
david@machineA:/data/queue/data$ ls -lrth
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david  12K Apr 11 18:58 1428800400
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david  12K Apr 11 19:58 1428804000
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david  12K Apr 11 20:58 1428807600
```

I want to run a command from this directory only - "/data/queue/data" which can print me the folder names and the files names for that folder if they have my string in their contents.

```
david@machineA:/data/queue/data$ some command to find the folder and files which has my string.
```

Comment: You mean like `find /data/queue/data -name *badezimmer*`? Or are you talking about files containing the string *in their contents*?

Comment: I mean files containing strings in their contents. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then a simple `grep -rl badezimmer /data/queue/data` will work.

Comment: I see. And suppose if it is a two words, then I can use like that `grep -rl "A B" /data/queue/data`. Right?

Comment: Yes - that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, the following will do what you want:

```
grep -rl 'badezimmer' /data/queue/data
```

From the man page for `grep(1)`:

> ```
> -l, --files-with-matches
>        Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print  the  name of each input file from which output would normally have been
>        printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.
>
> -r, --recursive
>        Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the  command  line.
>        This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
> ```